# Cannot turn on Bluetooth on Ubuntu 23.10 (Asus ROG ROG Flow X13 GV302XV)

Tags: bluetooth, asus, bluetooth-speaker, 23.10

Cannot turn on bluetooth, and the speaker not work also. in fedora 39 the speaker not working but the bluetooth work.
Please help!!!

```
Audio:
Device-1: NVIDIA vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie:
    speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 8 bus-ID: 01:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:22be
  Device-2: AMD Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 69:00.1 chip-ID: 1002:1640
  Device-3: AMD ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor vendor: ASUSTeK
    driver: snd_pci_ps v: kernel pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 69:00.5
    chip-ID: 1022:15e2
  Device-4: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio vendor: ASUSTeK
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 69:00.6 chip-ID: 1022:15e3
  API: ALSA v: k6.5.0-10-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.79 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse
    status: active 2: wireplumber status: active 3: pipewire-alsa type: plugin
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device driver: btusb v: 0.8 type: USB
    rev: 2.1 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 1-4:3 chip-ID: 0489:e0f6
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 3 state: down
    bt-service: enabled,running rfk-block: hardware: no software: no
    address: <filter>

lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 3277:0018 Sonix Technology Co., Ltd. USB2.0 FHD UVC WebCam
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e0f6 Foxconn / Hon Hai Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b05:19b6 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. N-KEY Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.280477] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    6.620099] systemd[1]: systemd-pcrmachine.service - TPM2 PCR Machine ID Measurement was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/StubPcrKernelImage-4a67b082-0a4c-41cf-b6c7-440b29bb8c4f).
[    7.135709] mt7921e 0000:06:00.0: WM Firmware Version: ____000000, Build Time: 20230627143946
[    8.066589] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x08002300
[    8.068515] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.10 DEC: 5 VEP: 0 Revision: 0
[    8.068525] amdgpu 0000:69:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[    8.582463] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    8.582519] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    8.582522] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.582528] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.582532] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.582540] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    9.459754] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    9.459767] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    9.459783] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   10.612354] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
```

---

what about the speaker ? The bluetooth is working now (Thanks to @Jeremy31) but still no sound :) please help.

Comment: Please attach more system info: `sudo apt install inxi` and then `inxi -Fxxzc0` in terminal

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: @RA Thanks, wait ill add in question

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks, wait ill add in question

Answer (score 1):

To fix the Bluetooth, check `mokutil --sb` as Secure Boot needs to be disabled, once disabled then do

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-6.5.git
sudo dkms add ./bluetooth-6.5
sudo dkms install btusb/4.1
```

Reboot

Comment: OMG Thankssss you made it !!!
now the problem is the sound. I cannot hear anything. 

I will make a new thread for this

Comment: Can you click the checkmark to accept the answer and possibly help others with the same issue?

Comment: Has anything stopped working? I have a GV302XI and I get an error in the last command:
error: ‘struct hci_dev’ has no member named ‘dump’
 4736 |                 hdev->dump.coredump(hdev);

Comment: @SantiIglesias are you using the 6.5 kernel?

Comment: 6.2.0-37-generic is that the problem? @Jeremy31 can you explain what is exactly this repository? Is it cloned from other and patched?

Comment: @SantiIglesias this only works for the 6.5 kernels, ask a question and include results for `lsusb; sudo dmesg|egrep -i 'blue|firm'` and I might be able to help

Comment: It is working! I installed Ubuntu 23.10 which comes with kernel 2.5 and works like a charm! Although I would like to know what I have installed and what it solves :D

Comment: @SantiIglesias I would have to know more details about you hardware to know if my fixes on github did anything

Comment: I can't add the output of that command in a comment, too large, but It definitely worked, I can now pair bluetooth devices and even audio is working trough them (main laptop speaker still not working, but that not what this is about)